# Conditional filtering inside of for loop, gives empty Series/dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a 100x15 DF, `comparison_df`.

[image]

I have a list of tuples, (shortened version):

```
watchlist = [('Admiral Group', 820.0), ('3i', 4300.0), ('AstraZeneca', 7500.0), 
             ('Ashtead Group', 920.0)]
```

I want to iterate through this list of tuples and find entries in my DF which meet some conditional filters:

```
for a, (company, target_price) in enumerate(watchlist):
    companyFilter = comparison_df["Company"][((comparison_df["Mid-price (p)"] <= target_price) 
                          | (comparison_df["Buy Ratio"] >= 0.5))
                          & (comparison_df["Company"] == "{}".format(company))]
    print(companyFilter)
```

This works, but if I give the conditional statements to `comparison_df["Company"]`, so that I can just get the company name returned, I end up with empty Series:

```
95    TUI
Name: Company, dtype: object
Series([], Name: Company, dtype: object)
6    AstraZeneca
Name: Company, dtype: object
90    Standard Chartered
Name: Company, dtype: object
Series([], Name: Company, dtype: object)
```

How can I get just the Company names out of this data? Appending `.values[0]` doesn't work, because there are iterations of the loop that return junk, apparently, and this throws up an error:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, using .loc or .iloc followed by the column will get you the single scalar value.   e.g. comparison_df.iloc[95]["Company"]   Of course this requires that your expression return one and only one index value.   When your conditional expression returns a boolean mask (set of True/False values) then you'll get a series back.

Of course you could do a .values.tolist()[0] and get the first, but...

Let's step back for a second - what are we trying to do?   Get the companies  with a mid-price less than an enumerated target, or with a Buy Ratio > .5 - sounds like a job for Pandas...    Like, the whole job is a job for Pandas.

1. join your watch list to your dataframe, keying on the company name.
2. apply your criteria to produce a list of companies that satisfy it.

So your query changes to something like this:

```
comparison_df[((comparison_df["Mid-price (p)"] <= comparison_df["target_price"]) 
                          | (comparison_df["Buy Ratio"] >= 0.5))]["Company"].values.tolist()
```

No looping required.

If you're not sure how to do the merge, you just create a dataframe from your watchlist:

```
watchlist = [('Admiral Group', 820.0), ('3i', 4300.0), ('AstraZeneca', 7500.0), 
             ('Ashtead Group', 920.0)] 
joinDF = pd.DataFrame(watchlist, columns=["Company", "target_price"])
```

then left-outer join it to your comparison_df on "Company"